# Is my HDD falling?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I tested my HDD with command:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

I checked status of test with command:

smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda

This is the output:

```
smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [x86_64-linux-2.6.18-348.3.1.el5] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       80%      6685         353374938
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6662         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       80%      6658         353374929
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5741         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4818         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4818         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3658         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3592         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3591         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3591         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3026         -
#12  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       839         -
```

This is output for command:

smartctl -a /dev/sda

```
smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [x86_64-linux-2.6.18-348.3.1.el5] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3750525AS
Serial Number:    9VPETFD8
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 03f7ea511
Firmware Version: JC4B
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Sun Apr  7 00:02:08 2013 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 120) The previous self-test completed having
                                        the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 127) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   111   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       34982547
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       7
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       318459251
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       6685
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       7
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       131
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   058   050   045    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 39/44)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 26 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   027   016   000    Old_age   Always       -       34982547
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       183227599821350
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       219522801
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1847102017

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       80%      6685         353374938
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6662         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       80%      6658         353374929
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5741         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4818         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4818         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3658         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3592         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3591         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3591         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3026         -
#12  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       839         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: You seem to have only 3 bad sectors. I had 36 reallocated sectors on a hard disk and it worked fine for about 9 months or more until I replaced it with something else. Though, this is only anecdotal, there are disks and disks. The safest thing to do is replace it.

Comment: Only "3" Offline_Uncorrectable is **the beginning of the end**. Listen to [mdpc](http://serverfault.com/a/496914/140016) and @CristianCiupitu, and replace it ASAP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your hard disk is failing.  I'd replace it relatively quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Your Seagate Drive has only done 6,5 K Hours of work and is starting to fail, this is rather unusual.

SMART is however telling you to replace it.

Normally HDD's are designed to last at least 10K hours, so you might still have a chance to replace this under Guarantee, but I would not waste too much time on this.

Doing a fast search on the Net came up with some complaints with this Drive. Seems like Seagate bought Maxtor, and since then have produced rather questionable SATA Products.

If you buy a new one, rather go for Western Digital. If you have the money, I would suggest a Intel SSD drive.

Whatever you do, now is the time to make backups of your DATA

Comment: I had bad lucks on these two brands (SMART #5 error occured in less than half a year), maybe it's because of I bought HDDs from internet (newegg China), you know, bad things can happened in logistics/delivery step. Then I bought a Hitachi HDD **from local market**, good luck is back now (more than 1 year)